# Fastest Way in vbscript to Check if a String Contains a Word/Phrase from a List of Many Words/Phrases

Tags: regex, string, loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I am implementing a function which is to check a blurb (e.g. a message/forum post, etc) against a (potentially long) list of banned words/phrases, and simply return true if any one or more of the words is found in the blurb, and false if not.

This is to be done in vbScript.

The old developer currently has a very large IF statement using instr() e.g.

```
    If  instr(ucase(contactname), "KORS") > 0 OR _ 
        instr(ucase(contactname), "D&G") > 0 OR _   
        instr(ucase(contactname), "DOLCE") > 0 OR _     
        instr(ucase(contactname), "GABBANA") > 0 OR _   
        instr(ucase(contactname), "TIFFANY") > 0 OR _
        '...
    Then
```

I am trying to decide between two solutions to replace the above code:

1. Using regular expression to find matches, where the regex would be a simple (but potentially long) regex like this: `"KORS|D&G|DOLCE|GABBANA|TIFFANY"` and so on, and we would do a regular expression test to return true if any one or more of the words is found.
2. Using an array where each array item contains a banned word, and loop through each array item checking it against the blurb. Once a match is found the loop would terminate and a variable would be set to TRUE, etc.

It seems to me that the regular expression option is the best, since it is one "check" e.g. the blurb tested against the pattern. But I am wondering if the potentially very long regex pattern would add enough processing overhead to negate the simplicity and benefit of doing the one "check" vs. the many "checks" in the array looping scenario?

I am also open to additional options which I may have overlooked.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - to clarify, this is for a SINGLE test of one "blurb" e.g. a comment, a forum post, etc. against the banned word list. It only runs one time during a web request. The benchmarking should test size of the word list and NOT the number of executions of the use case.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Personally I'd probably go with the RegEx approach but that's not to say I haven't used the Array approach myself in the past. As for the RegEx performance, do a simple test case and see how it goes.

Comment: I had the same problem but with PHP, and the regex way was from far faster than nested loops. If you try this way, don't forget to bound your pattern: `\b(?:GABBANA|TIFFANY|DOLCE)\b` to increase performances.

Comment: An other thing you can do, is to factorize the list, example: `\b(?:D(?:&G|OLCE)|G(?:ABANA|...)|...)\b`, then you reduce the number of tests to 26 (or the number of different first character) to fail on the first character.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to _benchmark_ both methods.

Comment: I'd recommend the regex method as it's likely faster (and definitely easier) but as mentioned by @ridgerunner the only way to really know is to benchmark.

Comment: If you test the second method, don't forget to exit the loops at the first occurence.

Comment: Could someone please provide the VBScrpt for using regex to check a list of words are in a string? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me (without checking) that such complex regexp would be slower, and also evaluating such complex 'Or' statement wold be slow (VBS will evaluate all alternatives).
Should all alternatives be evaluated to know expression value - of course not.
What I would do, is to populate an array with banned words and then iterate through it, checking if the word is within text being searched -  **and if word is found discontinue iteration**.
You could store the most 'popular' banned words on the top of the array (some kind of rank), so you would be most likely to find them in few first steps.
Another benefit of using array is that it is easier to manage its' values compared to 'hardcoded' values within `if` statement.

I just tested 1 000 000 checks with regexp ("word|anotherword") vs InStr for each word and it seems I was not right.
Regex check took 13 seconds while InStr 71 seconds.
Edited: Checking each word separately with regexp took 78 seconds.
Still I think that if you have many banned words checking them one by one and breaking if any is found would be faster (after last check I would consider joining them by (5? 10?) and checking not such complex regexp each time).

Comment: Your results confirm my initial gut feelings.  However, I think in my case, the test needs to be a bit different. You see, only one blurb is ever checked at time. e.g. this is done at the beginning of certain web page requests e.g. the ones which submit data to a form, etc.

I am thinking that the test needs to be a loop with say, 500 iterations/comparisons, then the regex comparison with a pattern containing the same 500 terms (if it can even be that long)

I have currently implemented the regex solution and my word list currently has about 150 entries, and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a string that contains all of your words. Surround each word with a delimiter.

```
Const TEST_WORDS = "|KORS|D&G|DOLCE|GABBANA|TIFFANY|"
```

Then, test to see if your word (plus delimiter) is contained within this string:

```
If InStr(1, TEST_WORDS, "|" & contactname & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    ' Found word
End If
```

No need for array loops or regular expressions.

Comment: But you need to check *each* word of the 'blurp' (i.e. message, forum post). And: You'd need a front delimiter too, otherwise you'd find a (legal) ANY| in TIFFANY|.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner You're right. I was misled by his sample code because I thought he was just testing one word (`contactname`) against many. (You're right about the delimiter, too. I'll fix that.)